# Measuring process time of a multi-thread code in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, profiling

I am running the following code try to measure how long my PG process finish, however, the "toc-tic" displays as soon as the whole loop finish, is there any way that I can measure the total time and time for individual thread? Thanks

```
tic = time.clock()
for i in range(0,2):        
    start = i * step
    end = start + step

    pg = PatternGenerator()
    pg.counter = start
    pg.pos = i
    pg.data = lines[start:end]  

    pg.start()

toc = time.clock()

print toc - tic
```

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 2):

**Join the threads, before toc!**

You can put the objects to a list, then call join on them!

before the for :

```
pglist = [] 
... start the threads...

for pg in pglist:
  pg.join()

toc = time.clock()

print toc - tic
```